# How to contact my previous boss for a job

Tags: job-change

I am just wondering what would be the best method for contacting and asking my previous boss to see about a job again.

I had previously worked for this company X as a short term contractor. I got an offer another company that was working with a recruiter before actually starting. So after working for company X for about 4 months I took the job with Company Y.

That was a terrible experience so after 90 days I asked company X for a full time position. I worked there for two years and really enjoyed the job but I didn't like the commute so much. I got another offer for 50% more than I was making and a 5 min commute at company Z.

Well it turns out after just about two years Company Z was sold and the new owners want to close the office and move it. I will be getting my relocation offer tomorrow but I would like to open communication to the Company X again.

I am just not sure about the best method to do that after leaving twice before. It was honestly the best and most enjoyable job I had ever had.

Comment: Have you considered looking for a new position?  I doubt the old company will match your new salary.  So best bet will be to find a new company that will

Comment: You already left twice and betrayed their trust twice.  I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @Jack - Leaving a position is not a betrayal of trust.  If a company wants to ensure X years of employment, it would be specified in the employee contract.  When company Z was sold, it wasn't a betrayal of the employees either.  It was just business.  Leaving a job for a higher wage is equally, 'just business'

Comment: @RobP. Yea but he already has a track record of working for them and then leaving, twice already.  I'm pretty sure it costs them time and money to train another person and transfer projects so why would they trust him to not leave yet again and cause them more work yet again?

Comment: @Jack - That's certainly true, they might not trust him not to leave.  On the flip side, they underpaid what he could find elsewhere by 50%.  How can draksia trust this company?  In any case, those are questions for them to sort out, and I think you have a valid point that frequently changing jobs can make someone a less desirable candidate; my objection was really just to the idea that it was a betrayal.  Intentionally disclosing confidential information, lying, sabotaging, etc...those would be betrays.  Leaving for a significant wage increase isn't (imho).

Comment: @Jack - his position was initially that of a short-term contractor.  Leaving for company Y for a permanent position is not only not a betrayal of trust, it's expected with short-term contractors.  He worked for X for two years, which is not longevity, but it isn't job hopping.  50% pay increase and a 5 minute commute is a no-brainer.  He's stayed with X for two years, again, pretty stable, and the company has been sold and his job has been relocated.  No red flags for him over that. If I was company "X," I would have concerns over him coming back to the same unpopular commute as before.

Comment: s/b "He stayed with Z for two years, again" after the "no-brainer" sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have actually had a somewhat similar situation, where I worked for a company multiple times over a period of around 13 years.  When I finished a contract elsewhere, I would contact them, tell them I was finishing x contract soon.  I had a good working relationship with management and they usually were very responsive to my questions about if they had any work available.  Mostly it was a short term contract, twice I took a permanent role with them.

So it comes down to how well you get on with the people you used to work with.  If the answer is "well", then a phone call never hurts :)

Comment: I decided to email him and see about getting lunch next week, He seemed delighted to get together so yeah maybe it will work out.